# What is the text "ECNARUS" in pdf documents?

Tags: pdf

I'm parsing pdf documents and have encountered a watermarked set of characters, "ECNARUS" in my documents. I thought it was a mistake, but when I search for the term "ECNARUS" on the web (https://www.google.com/search?q=ecnarus), I get many pdf documents that, when searched, reveal these same characters, typically hidden in the document.

What do these characters mean?

Comment: What part of the PDF is this in? Can you share a specific example so that a knowledgable person can examine it? I don't really find any. Not sure what you mean by watermarked.

Comment: I did a Google search for "ecnarus" and the first link (besides this article) is this PDF below. If you search the pdf for the text "ecnarus", you can find it hidden under the word "Insurance" on the right: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO1OnupoH_AhWnAzQIHYa5BbcQFnoECA4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbeacheswatch.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F04%2FWhos_knocking_at_your_door_HORIZONTAL-ENGLISH-508-002.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0fgm6kn5I4jVjNsuMltfrE

There are several others, as well.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the missing reference

Comment: It's simply the word "insurance" backwards. All of the PDFs in the link you provided contain it

Comment: Any idea why it's backwards and why it's hidden behind other text in all these docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @j08691 already pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285002/what-is-the-text-ecnarus-in-pdf-documents?noredirect=1#comment134535191_76285002):

> It's simply the word "insurance" backwards. All of the PDFs in the link you provided contain it

You then [wondered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285002/what-is-the-text-ecnarus-in-pdf-documents?noredirect=1#comment134544760_76285002):

> Any idea why it's backwards and why it's hidden behind other text in all these docs?

Well, it is not "hidden behind other text" at all, at least not in case of [the document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO1OnupoH_AhWnAzQIHYa5BbcQFnoECA4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbeacheswatch.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F04%2FWhos_knocking_at_your_door_HORIZONTAL-ENGLISH-508-002.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0fgm6kn5I4jVjNsuMltfrE) you pointed out in a comment. Here the word "Insurance" vertically written on the side is drawn using these instructions:

```
0 14 -14 0 779.2038 370.4745 Tm
[(e) 857.2 (c) 876.2 (n) 927.2 (a) 755.2 (r) 739.2 (u) 856.2 (s) 1100.3 (In) ] TJ
```

The first line sets the text matrix to the 90° vertical direction.
The second line then first draws the 'e', then goes back before it, then draws the 'c', then goes back before it, then ..., then draws the 's', then goes back before it, then draws the 'In'.

If you ignore the "going before the letter just drawn", you get "ecnarus" followed by "In".

Thus, this simply is a combination of the PDF producer writing vertical text in an unnecessarily weird way and text extractors (both Google and Adobe Reader) getting baffled by this weird way and interpreting the writing backwards.

Also this is not the only weird text find in your example PDF. If you search for "tnemnrveGo" you'll find it "hidden" behind the vertical "Government". Similarly "rehOt" is hidden behind the vertical "Other".